# Where to write set JAVA_OPTS in setenv.bat for tomcat 7 windows installation (as a service)

Tags: windows, spring, batch-file, tomcat, tomcat7

There are various similar questions but none answers where to embed the environment variable. Unfortunately, in my case there is already a file named `setenv.bat` which contains a lot of code.

There is a lot of code in it. So the question is where do I write (on which line at what place within `setenv.bat`)

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dblockchain.callbackUrl=http://example.com/"
```

I wrote it at the beginning of `setenv.bat` but it doesn't work.

FYI : I installed tomcat using the windows installer, hence, I have `tomcat7w.exe`

I'm running tomcat as a windows service

I'm trying to access this variable through Spring in my webapp as :

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['blockchain.callbackUrl']?:'http://localhost:8080/'}")
    private String callbackHost;
```

**Update**

I tried setting it in catalina.bat, still didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

When we create a service from Tomcat installation on windows, such parameters have to be defined in `service.bat` before installing the service with `service.bat install` command.

```
--JvmOptions "-Dblockchain.callbackUrl=http://www.example.com/;-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME
```

Add the environment variables to `JvmOptions` in `service.bat` as shown above.